# reset autoincrement primary key sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table Post with 1000 rows, where id_post is primary key Set to `autoincrement`

**OLD**

```
id_post | post
  1        hi1
  2        hi2
   ...
 1000     hi1000
```

I deleted rows from 301 to 1000. So I have now a list of rows from 1 to 300.

**NEW**

```
id_post | post
  1        hi1
  2        hi2
   ...
 300     hi300
```

**PROBLEM**

when trying to add a new row, `id_post` starts at 1001, how do I reset the table and make it to start from 301?

Comment: And after exhausting 700 IDs in gaps what will you do? AUTOINCREMENT should be left as it is. You cannot guarantee no gaps because it was not designed that way. `ALTER TABLE post AUTO_INCREMENT = 300;`

Comment: I know it should be left. But this is a posts table, where there are default posts and users posts. the 300 are default posts.

Comment: 1) create new table from 1 to 1000 
2) delete the old table 
3) alter the name of the new table to the name of the old one

Comment: @LukaszSzozda approach is the way to go. thank you.  Lukasz feel free to post  an answer to mark it. thank you it worked.

Comment: @Dan -  you can also set the id to 1 (like answer from Lukasz Szozda) Mysql will then get the next free id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would leave gap as it is. If you really want to change it you could use:

```
 ALTER TABLE post AUTO_INCREMENT = 300;
 -- around 700 insterts
 ALTER TABLE post AUTO_INCREMENT = ?; -- where ? is max value of id_post
```

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate that table in order to reset your identity column. Like this:

```
truncate table [table_name]
```

Or you can use CHECKIDENT command:

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, 0)
```